# blogdown not rendering in Netlify, despite working in RStudio

Tags: r, netlify, blogdown

Here is my GitHub repository: https://github.com/millerchangym/mathstatsblog

You can see below that I can see the post rendered in the viewer in bottom right in RStudio:

[image]

I did run `blogdown::serve_site()` before pushing to GitHub.

```
blogdown::hugo_version()
[1] ‘0.55.5’
```

After deploying via Netlify, I get the following deploy log:

```
7:54:47 PM: Build ready to start
7:55:03 PM: build-image version: d5d16c91ca3e1e5a990086daa8a1d5bd8564d12a
7:55:03 PM: build-image tag: v3.2.2
7:55:03 PM: buildbot version: 93c10be3dc42bccef2b5600a7e10ec1d4a1c7051
7:55:03 PM: Fetching cached dependencies
7:55:04 PM: Starting to download cache of 255.1KB
7:55:04 PM: Finished downloading cache in 161.833458ms
7:55:04 PM: Starting to extract cache
7:55:04 PM: Failed to fetch cache, continuing with build
7:55:04 PM: Starting to prepare the repo for build
7:55:04 PM: No cached dependencies found. Cloning fresh repo
7:55:04 PM: git clone https://github.com/millerchangym/mathstatsblog
7:55:06 PM: Preparing Git Reference refs/heads/master
7:55:07 PM: Starting build script
7:55:07 PM: Installing dependencies
7:55:08 PM: v10.15.3 is already installed.
7:55:09 PM: Now using node v10.15.3 (npm v6.4.1)
7:55:09 PM: Attempting ruby version 2.6.2, read from environment
7:55:11 PM: Using ruby version 2.6.2
7:55:11 PM: Using PHP version 5.6
7:55:11 PM: Installing Hugo 0.55.5
7:55:13 PM: Hugo Static Site Generator v0.55.5-A83256B9C/extended linux/amd64 BuildDate: 2019-05-02T14:12:43Z
7:55:13 PM: Started restoring cached go cache
7:55:13 PM: Finished restoring cached go cache
7:55:13 PM: unset GOOS;
7:55:13 PM: unset GOARCH;
7:55:13 PM: export GOROOT='/opt/buildhome/.gimme/versions/go1.12.linux.amd64';
7:55:13 PM: export PATH="/opt/buildhome/.gimme/versions/go1.12.linux.amd64/bin:${PATH}";
7:55:13 PM: go version >&2;
7:55:13 PM: export GIMME_ENV='/opt/buildhome/.gimme/env/go1.12.linux.amd64.env';
7:55:13 PM: go version go1.12 linux/amd64
7:55:13 PM: Installing missing commands
7:55:13 PM: Verify run directory
7:55:13 PM: Executing user command: hugo
7:55:13 PM: Building sites …
7:55:13 PM: WARN 2019/05/07 00:55:13 found no layout file for "HTML" for "page": You should create a template file which matches Hugo Layouts Lookup Rules for this combination.
7:55:13 PM: WARN 2019/05/07 00:55:13 found no layout file for "HTML" for "taxonomyTerm": You should create a template file which matches Hugo Layouts Lookup Rules for this combination.
7:55:13 PM: WARN 2019/05/07 00:55:13 found no layout file for "HTML" for "home": You should create a template file which matches Hugo Layouts Lookup Rules for this combination.
7:55:13 PM: WARN 2019/05/07 00:55:13 found no layout file for "HTML" for "taxonomyTerm": You should create a template file which matches Hugo Layouts Lookup Rules for this combination.
7:55:13 PM:                    | EN
7:55:13 PM: +
7:55:13 PM: ------------------+----+
7:55:13 PM:   Pages            |  3
7:55:13 PM:   Paginator pages  |  0
7:55:13 PM:   Non-page files   |  0
7:55:13 PM:   Static files     |  3
7:55:13 PM:   Processed images |  0
7:55:13 PM:   Aliases          |  0
7:55:13 PM:   Sitemaps         |  1
7:55:13 PM:   Cleaned          |  0
7:55:13 PM: Total in 10 ms
7:55:13 PM: Build script success
7:55:13 PM: Starting cache prep script
7:55:13 PM: Caching artifacts
7:55:13 PM: Started saving pip cache
7:55:13 PM: Finished saving pip cache
7:55:13 PM: Started saving emacs cask dependencies
7:55:13 PM: Finished saving emacs cask dependencies
7:55:13 PM: Started saving maven dependencies
7:55:13 PM: Finished saving maven dependencies
7:55:13 PM: Started saving boot dependencies
7:55:13 PM: Finished saving boot dependencies
7:55:13 PM: Started saving go dependencies
7:55:13 PM: Finished saving go dependencies
7:55:15 PM: Cache script success
7:55:15 PM: Starting to deploy site from 'public'
7:55:15 PM: Creating deploy tree 
7:55:15 PM: 0 new files to upload
7:55:15 PM: 0 new functions to upload
7:55:17 PM: Starting post processing
7:55:17 PM: Post processing done
7:55:17 PM: Site is live
7:55:26 PM: Finished processing build request in 23.212737452s
7:55:27 PM: Shutting down logging, 0 messages pending
```

Upon clicking "Preview deploy" in Netlify, I get

[image]

I find these lines particularly peculiar, but searching hasn't given me any additional insight as to what these lines mean:

```
7:55:13 PM: WARN 2019/05/07 00:55:13 found no layout file for "HTML" for "page": You should create a template file which matches Hugo Layouts Lookup Rules for this combination.
    7:55:13 PM: WARN 2019/05/07 00:55:13 found no layout file for "HTML" for "taxonomyTerm": You should create a template file which matches Hugo Layouts Lookup Rules for this combination.
    7:55:13 PM: WARN 2019/05/07 00:55:13 found no layout file for "HTML" for "home": You should create a template file which matches Hugo Layouts Lookup Rules for this combination.
    7:55:13 PM: WARN 2019/05/07 00:55:13 found no layout file for "HTML" for "taxonomyTerm": You should create a template file which matches Hugo Layouts Lookup Rules for this combination.
```

Comment: Your repo on github doesn't seem to contain the `layouts` folder from the theme, which seems to match up with the errors you're getting.

Comment: @Marius You solved the problem, thank you! The solution was to remove `*.html` from the `.gitignore`... I've learned my lesson now. Please feel free to put your comment as an answer and I will mark it as best answer.

Answer (score 0):

You have to **build** the site  before pushing it to your github repository. Try `blogdown::build_site()`, then add, commit and push to github and see if it works

Take a look [here](https://bookdown.org/yihui/blogdown/methods.html). If you have `.Rmd` files, you might need to use the argument `method = "html"` when you build the site